# How to upgrade Typescript to the latest version?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.2
Some time ago I installed Typescript and today I'd like to upgrade that installation to the latest version available (so far, v0.8.3). 
I wrote this command from the terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

But this is what I got on the display:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
/usr/local/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
typescript@0.8.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
```

Does this means that I still have version 0.8.0 installed on my computer?
I tried to see if the tsc command has a `-v` or a `-version` parameter but I haven't found it, so I still uncertain if I have upgraded Typescript to the latest release or if I'm still stuck with an older version.

Comment: You might be able to check the version of TypeScript by using this command: `npm view typescript version` on the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just realised that I was using an old version of npm. I have upgraded npm to the latest version, then re-installed typescript and now I have the latest version of typescript installed on my computer.

Comment: Why should the npm version matter?

Answer (score 80):

I had the same problem below procedure worked for me

**Update NPM**

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

**Update typescript**

```
npm -g upgrade typescript
```

or

```
npm install typescript@latest -g
```

now you should see

```
tsc --version
```

**Version 2.1.5**

Comment: I was typing `npm update -g tsc` and received no error messages, but nothing worked :))) Don't make my mistake and mind the syntax (`upgrade` not `update`) and the package name (`typescript` not `tsc`) :D it's `npm upgrade -g typescript` as @PuneethRai has written :)

Comment: tsc is binary file and typescript is the package name which includes that binary . So ideally you need upgrade the package and not binary . So do upgrade the package which contains the binary . So you need to do npm -g upgrade typescript

Comment: Thanks! I have also just discovered that `npm update` or `npm up` are just aliases for `npm upgrade`. So my main mistake was thinking that package name was `tsc`...

Comment: Just wanted to add an additional note - we hit this same issue, but it was because running `npm install typescript@latest -g` didn't work. It errored out since, for some reason, it didn't want to update the Symlink. We just added `--force` and that forced it to update. It may have been because the old version of typescript was over 5 years old...

Answer (score 78):

Since selected correct answer didn't help me I figured I'd share how I resolved the issue.

I had to remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\` from my PATH.

After that I could run this command and see the version I was expecting:

```
C:\>tsc --version
message TS6029: Version 1.5.3
```

Comment: hey I am having the same problem, how did you remove the  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\`  path , i am not able to find the path....

Comment: @akash_sinha13134 Here's an article on how to remove variables from your PATH: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-edit-or-delete-environment-variables-windows-7-windows-8

Comment: Maybe we should move this answer to a Windows questions.

Comment: @BenR yeah... i knew that, but was not able to find it.. it was just as you told, and it worked, thanks.. :)

Comment: just to clarify (because I always forget) you need to open a new cmd prompt to apply any changes make to the environment variables.

Answer (score 17):

For those still struggling with that - try running `WHERE tsc` in Command Prompt or Node.js Command Prompt and you'll get all the locations it is installed. Remove the excessive location from PATH env var.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me since I had apparently installed it via yarn at some point in the past.  using `npm install` was doing no good at all.

Answer (score 14):

Even when i installed latest typescript, still i was getting version as 1.0.3 when doing tsc -v

The corrected answer didn't help me , but followed @BenR approach, removed this PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\ from System Variables

[image]

and then opened new windows command prompt and then typed

```
tsc -v
Version 2.3.3
```

So now i was able to compile the typescript files using `tsc file.ts`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 14):

Open a command line tool `cmd.exe/Git Bash` and execute:

```
 npm install -g typescript@latest
```

The command will do the following:

Check if Typescript is installed and ..

1. if installed already, ***update*** it to the latest version
2. if not installed, ***install*** the latest version

It has been reported that the following command will not work reliably when you already have typescript installed:

```
npm update -g typescript@latest
```

---

**Test the version** using

```
tsc -v  // prints out the locally installed typescript version
```

[image]

Furthermore you can check, which is the latest available version for typescript in the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/):

```
npm view typescript version  // prints the latest available version in the npm registry
```

Comment: When I type `tsc -v` I get an error that a version already exists.  The error says to: _"Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm with --force to overwrite files recklessly."_   I want to follow your solution, but After you check for latest version, how do you uninstall it so that the latest is installed?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Linux, possibly related to using node version manager.

I fixed it by finding where tsc was and then manually going in and deleting those folders

```
$ which tsc
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/tsc

$ cd /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/
$ ll
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant       38 Nov 30 10:32 tsc -> ../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant       43 Nov 30 10:32 tsserver -> ../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver*
...

$ rm -rf ../lib/node_modules/typescript/ tsc tsserver
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I had Visual Studio installed on my Windows OS computer, which added its own version of TypeScript installation into the System Path
2. Uninstalled 'TypeScript for Visual Studio' from Programs and Features(or 'Add or remove programs')
3. Installed latest typescript. From command prompt 'npm install -g typescript@latest'
4. Issue solved!

*I know this is an old Question, but I faced a similar issue and none of the answers here solved it, posting my answer for anyone else in the same boat.*

Comment: I'm using Win 10 and I can't find _"Programs and Features"_ in a search.  What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Its now 'Add or remove programs', I guess the old control panel one has phased out in updates since then.

Comment: Was using Windows 7 then. I've updated the answer to include the Windows 10 one ('add or remove programs')

Comment: I appreciate your adding Windows 10 location!

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this issue on the windows 8 machine with blocked admin access where I was unable to uninstall global typescript, modify `PATH` etc.

Here's how to launch typescript projects in this case:

1. install local typescript version for project `npm install typescript@latest` **( avoid `-g` param)**
2. add build scripts to `package.json` e.g.

   `scripts: {
       "clean": "rimraf coverage build tmp",
       "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
       "build:watch": "tsc -w -p tsconfig.release.json",
       "lint": "tslint -t stylish --project \"tsconfig.json\"",
       "test": "jest --coverage",
       "test:watch": "jest --watch"
   }`
3. run typescript compiler with the local version of typescript via `npm run build:watch` which will launch `tsc -w -p tsconfig.release.json` using project's local `tsc` from `node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 9/26/2022**

After running `npm install typescript@latest -g` I got the errors:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\chrisds\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\chrisds\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chrisds\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-26T20_55_57_959Z-debug-0.log
```

So I found the path and deleted all instances of tsc i.e.: `tsc`, `tsc.cmd`, `tsc.psl`, `tsserver`, `tsserver.cmd`, `tsserver.psl`

And then ran `npm install typescript@latest -g` again and it worked.

C:\Users\chrisds\Documents\typescript-angular>tsc -v

`Version 4.8.3`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and none of the popular answers resolved the problem for me. I'm on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017.

I tried using `where tsc` from the console to determine where the path to `tsc` was resolving. The first entry was similar to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\x.xx`. So I checked the `PATH` variable (both System and User) and that path was nowhere to be found.

I finally stumbled across this comment on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4971#issuecomment-144184935

Which pointed me in the right direction. I use `Console2` and my default console tab spawns a Visual Studio-enhanced console via this `.bat` file:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`

That `.bat` file doesn't contain anything TypeScript-specific, but it does run all the `.bat` files found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext`. And one of *those* files is conspicuously named `typescript.bat`. I simply renamed that filed to some other extension, then re-opened a console and now everything is great.

Not sure if this will bork up anything in Visual Studio, but I don't use it for TypeScript. And I suspect a future Visual Studio update may put that file back in place. But it works for now.

Comment: your solution sounds good AND is the most recent, but I DO use VS Code for Typescript (Angular) and I'd hate it if this solution messed up using TSC in VS Code.  Are you using VS Code or full Visual Studio IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `npm`, I used `npx` and it worked.