# Destructuring in Typescript cause compiler errors TS1008 and TS1005

Tags: compiler-errors, typescript, destructuring

I wanna use destructuring in typescript,example code:

```
var {first, second} = { first: "one", second: "two" }
console.log(first);
```

my compile command `tsc --t es5 destructuring.ts`,

typescript version `1.6.2`,

IDE is `vs code`.

then cause three errors:

`destructuring.ts(1,5): error TS1008: Unexpectedtoken; 'identifier' expected.`

`destructuring.ts(1,21): error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.`

`destructuring.ts(1,45): error TS1005: ';' expected.`;

In my desktop(*window 8.1 x64*),command `npm -g list` ,show `typescript@1.6.2`,and command  `tsc --version` show `Version 1.0.3.0`:

[image: typescript 1.0.3.0]

But in my laptop(*windows 7 x64*),the command `tsc --version` show `message TS6029: Version 1.6.2`:
[image: typescript 1.6.2]

Answer (score 6):

I am able to reproduce your problem in past versions of TypeScript, but not 1.6.2:

```
> tsc -v
Version 1.0.3.0
> tsc -t es5 destructuring.ts
error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'identifier' expected.
error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum ...
error TS1005: ';' expected.

> tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.6.2
> tsc -t es5 destructuring.ts
>
```

Please ensure you are actually using a version of TypeScript >= 1.5 in Visual Studio Code.

To fix your desktop to use the right version of TypeScript take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532656). Basically, you can see where `tsc` is running from by typing the command `where tsc` and you have to remove that directory from the path or delete that directory.