# Why I can't use watch by tsc?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript1.7

This is my current typescript and tsc versions:

```
> npm list typescript -g
└── typescript@1.7.5

> tsc -v
Version 1.0.3.0
```

The [doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) says `tsc` can use `-w` arg. I tried to uninstall and install the module, it never has the arg. What happened?

Please tell me what the latest `tsc` version is. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your `tsc` version is very old.

Comment: @Marty I had tried to install latest `tsc` but it's still `Version 1.0.3.0`.

Comment: My guess is that you have more than one `tsc` installed and the updated one is not picked up. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301451/could-you-tell-me-how-do-you-upgrade-typescript-to-the-latest-version?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I know what happened. [upgrading-on-windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)

My latest global modules locate on `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Because I set incomplete `path` in windows environment variables, It causes I can't call the newest modules.

Comment: Can you mark your own response as the correct answer? You may want to do that here so this question no longer appears open.

Comment: @Paarth If anyone has better answer than mine, I am welcome to mark   his/hers.