# How can I generate a tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript

How can I generate a `tsconfig.json` via the command line? 
I tried command `tsc init`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 731, accepted):

It is [supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3079) since the release of TypeScript 1.6.

The correct command is `--init` not `init`:

```
$ tsc --init
```

Try to run in your console the following to check the version:

```
$ tsc -v
```

If the version is older than 1.6 you will need to update:

```
$ npm install -g typescript
```

Remember that you need to install node.js to use npm.

Comment: if, like me, this didn't quite work for you - try the solution provided in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32532656/1732184 Cheers!

Comment: I was able to make it work without a global installation:

`npm i typescript`

`npx tsc --init`

Comment: for a local installation `node_modules/.bin/tsc --init`

Comment: Is this answer out of date? `npx tsc --init` returns "Unknown compiler option 'init'."

Comment: @AndyRay This fixed it for me: `sudo npm install typescript -g --force`

Comment: @nathanfranke you should NEVER install libraries as sudo, and --force isn't related to this instal issue. That probably means you're installing it to your system installed node, instead of a user (you) installed node using nvm

Comment: @AndyRay Running npm global without sudo: "or try running the command again as root/Administrator". However you're right that it's probably a better idea to modify the permissions.

Answer (score 89):

For those who have TypeScript installed as a local package (and possibly as a dev dependency) via:

```
$ npm install typescript --save-dev
```

...and who have added *tsc* script to package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "tsc": "tsc"
},
```

You can call `tsc --init` via `npm`:

```
$ npm run tsc -- --init
```

Comment: Why do we need the two dashes in between tsc and --init?

Comment: @lorless That's a delimiter so everything after `--` is treated as an argument to a script itself and is not parsed by `npm`.

Answer (score 83):

If you don't want to install TypeScript globally (which makes sense to me, so you don't need to update it constantly), you can use npx:

```bash
npx -p typescript tsc --init
```

The key point is using the `-p` flag to inform npx that the tsc binary belongs to the typescript package.

Comment: Why not just use `npx tsc --init`? If Typescript is installed as a local dev dependency, tsc will exist in `node_modules/.bin/tsc`.

Answer (score 58):

You need to have typescript library installed and then you can use

```
npx tsc --init
```

If the response is `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'init'.` that means the library is not installed

```
yarn add --dev typescript
```

or for npm

```
npm i --save-dev typescript
```

and run `npx` command again

I recommend not to install dependencies globally as it is easier to manage the versioning for each project. It is also easier for coworkers to see an install what is needed to run the project with one command.

Comment: I had this error: "This is not the tsc command you are looking for".
Using npx typescript --init worked, though.

Answer (score 29):

this worked for me:

```
tsc --init
```

Answer (score 17):

install TypeScript :

```
npm install typescript
```

add tsc script to package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc"
 },
```

run this:

```
npm run tsc -- --init
```

Answer (score 10):

i am using this,

```
yarn add -D typescript
yarn tsc --init
```

this fixed it for me

Answer (score 10):

```
npm install -g typescript 
tsc --init
```

Then sometimes after you globally updated typescript you probably again need to add it to your current project.

`npm install typecsript ts-node nodemon` - if you need it.

Comment: simple typo. It should tsc --init not int :-)

Answer (score 8):

Setup a ts project as following steps:

- install typescript `yarn global add typescript`
- create a **package.json**: run `yarn init` or setting defaults `yarn init -yp`
- create a **tsconfig.json**: run `tsc --init`
- (*optional) add **tslint.json**

The project structure seems like:

```
│  package.json
│  tsconfig.json
│  tslint.json
│  yarn.lock
│
├─dist
│      index.js
│
└─src
       index.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

the Normal way to generate the tsconfig file is to create a file with a name tsconfig.json then open {} ,inside this {} hit

> ctrl + spacebar  ( Windows)

> cmd + spacebar   (mac)

then choose compilationOptions then choose what options you need

---

For auto-generation (tsconfig.json) using VSCode terminal or any cmd on the same directory you wanna create :

> tsc --init

Answer (score 3):

In case someone comes here looking for what I was looking for, the tsconfig.json file with more options

```
npx tsconfig.json
```

was not working for me so instead:

```
npx tsconfig.json.cmd
```

gave me the tsconfig.json file I was looking for which offers more options

this worked for me on Windows

Answer (score 2):

`$ npm run tsc -- --init`
This worked for the below package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.19",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
```

Comment: This only works if you have "tsc": "tsc" in the scripts section of your package.json

Answer (score 2):

$ tsc --init
this command works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `npx tsc --init` without having to install any packages locally.

Answer (score 1):

**npx tsc --init**
For to run this command you must have the typescript installed

Comment: That is the same thing as what the top voted answers said...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to uninstall typescript first with the command:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

then use the [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) package in order to run:

```
choco install typescript
```

in PowerShell.

Comment: This is for windows only.

Answer (score 0):

From [2ality](https://2ality.com/2016/01/locally-installed-npm-executables.html). You can add a function in your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` to shortcut to the local bin path.

```sh
# in .zshrc:
function npm-do { (PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH; eval $@;) }

# working inside your directory:
npm-do tsc --init
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not used **npm install -g typescript** I only entered the command from the official documentation **npm install typescript --save-dev**, this is why I could not in my case use tsc -v or tsc --init ^^"