# Autocompletion isnt working with TypeScript + Node in VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

So if I write pure JS (.js) it is working like this:

[image]

But with TypeScript (.ts) it isnt working:

[image]

Comment: You should be using `import` for typescript anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: enable javascript intellisense in typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984035/vs-code-enable-javascript-intellisense-in-typescript-project)

Answer (score 0):

This may be 3 years late, but if anyone still encounters this issue:

You should use the more modern 'import' on your typescript file.

[image]

And in your package.json file, you should add:

```
{
    //...
    "type": "module",
}
```

If you don't add the type to your package.json, your node app won't work.