# VSCode and Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I decided to start using TypeScript, and so I set up a simple project. However, I seem to get some annoying linting errors which I do not know how to solve.

- Imports get the `Cannot find module 'X'. ts(2307)` error
- On my linux machine `Promise`s and `Error`s get the `Cannot find name 'X'` error
- On my linux machine `console.log/error` statements get a similar error and it recommends me to add `"dom"` to the `lib` in `tsconfig.json`, which doesn't help.

You can see the repo here (https://github.com/feareoc/chat). I'd appreciate any help for solve this problem!

Comment: default TS setup has no standard lib info included. you need to tell the TS engine about your environment, in your case it's the browser. Generate a `tsconfig.json` then config it. All important things are noted in comments in that file.

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916989/how-can-i-generate-tsconfig-json-file) to see how to generate a `tsconfig.json`. [This link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and [this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) are the docs. Look for `--lib` in last link.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your comments made me realise I have dockerized my node app, which means installing all modules (including typescript) only in the container. Unless I install the modules outside the container I still, obviously, get the `Cannot find module 'X'` error. Is there a way such that I don't have to install the modules outside the container for TS development, or do I have to stick with that for now?

Comment: check out [vscode remote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview). I haven't tested this feature, but it sounds like what you need

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work very well, only thing I cannot get working is getting the list of extensions till install in the container (I'm connecting to my docker-compose service), but that's for another thread