# Configure Typescript Compiler

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Do I need to config my tsconfig.json everytime I will create a typescript project or is there a way to config that once so that I can use the same setting on different projects?

PS: I'm a beginner

I want that when I set the tsconfig once, I can use it on different projects and not to config it again and again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a tsconfig.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916989/how-can-i-generate-a-tsconfig-json-file)

Comment: `tsc --init` will generate a tsconfig with sensible defaults