# AngularFire2: Cannot find namespace "firebase"

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to build a ng2 app with angularfire. Following the quickstart, I receive the following error:

```
cannot find namespace 'firebase'
```

Seems to be something with the typings, installed all of them though. Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as described in [the issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/461#issuecomment-242632690).

tsconfig.json:

`"types": [
   "jasmine",
   "firebase"
]`

Can't believe it's so easy to fix.

Comment: This didn't work for me though... What version of typescript do you use?

Comment: Version 2.1.0-dev.20160826

Comment: yeah same version for me - what about `tsc -v` what version does that report?

Comment: Really? I can't seem to get that to show anything but `Version 1.0.3.0` ?

Comment: Try to update globally and locally:
`npm install -g typescript@next`

`npm install typescript@next --save-dev`

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any impack on the `tsc` command. Perhaps my `tsc` is pointing to some (much) older and incompatible version of typescript...

Comment: It's weird. `typescript` does report and use the correct version, `tsc` is a completely different app and runs its own flow, uninstalling `typescript` does not affect `tsc` ...

Comment: if you write `tsc` in your prompt, what does it display on the first line?

Comment: `Version 2.1.0-dev.20160826`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122115/discussion-between-per-hornshoj-schierbeck-and-sandrooco).

Comment: Just wanted to point out - Sandrooco helped me find the problem by pointing me to another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301451/could-you-tell-me-how-do-you-upgrade-typescript-to-the-latest-version Turns out, i had to remove a PATH variable to stop my shell from using the *wrong* tsc - an old one that was installed in program files!

Comment: I revisited my project. This time with the correct tsc version. It still shows me the error from your initial post! Adding the types did not help :(

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck Dang, what was the error again? (That's what I got from changing the initial question... -.-) Let's go in chat again.

Comment: Actually, it's the error still in the question "cannot find namespace 'firebase'"

Answer (score 6):

If you have a fresh angular 2.0 CLI project - this will work - i don't know your particular setup:

1. make sure that your `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

"compilerOptions":
{

```
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
"../node_modules/@types"  /// - here - types are pointing to this @types folder inside node_modules.
]
```

}

2. create a new folder inside `@types` called `firebase`.
3. create a new file inside `firebase`, name it  `index.d.ts`
4. place the content form [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cdcarson/28399c50b02bf6c507fbf5b7b30daa31/raw/fa089d231ca4253d4715f8161efc6af74c972dfa/firebase-sdk-3-typings.d.ts) inside `index.d.ts`
5. [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md) are the official angularfire2 setup docs. The Troubleshooting section is not accurate - for an angular cli project. **Make sure not to place any declarations or stuff** inside tsconfig.json or typings.json as indicated there (as of now 28 sept 2016).

It looks like the recommended way to add typing's to an Angular 2.0 CLI project - is to add them inside node_modules/@types folder.. As you can see the jasmine typing's folder looks similar - and was automatically added there by the CLI scaffolding.

Comment: Life saver! Do as the man says if the other solutions aren't working. I spent many hours over a couple days banging up against this error and lots of resources telling me the wrong way to fix it. This worked (as of 10/02/2016)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that bug has already been reported and (hopefully) being worked on. Check it out here:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/461

Some people had success modifying typings.json (removing dependcy to firebase) or installing the @next version of typescript. Personally i'm stuck with the same error currently.

I hope the bug gets fixed eventually (soon ;))

EDIT: Seems like the 'bug' was a combination of several dependencies that had to be just right. In the end I had a `PATH` variable set to point to an old `tsc` installation under `Program Files`. For some reason, that was used instead of the (preferred one) from the node package `typescript`.

Comment: Well that sucks... Too bad there's no 100% fix. Thanks alot for your investigations and the help yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

try adding this line under your import

`declare let firebase: any; // <== THERE IS AN ERROR IN THE .d.ts file`

ie

`import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';`

`declare let firebase: any; // <== THERE IS AN ERROR IN THE .d.ts file`

you do this when you add vanilla js to typescript, its basically saying to typescript that ' firebase' variable exists even if you dont see it right now and it should hopefully remove the error, if it does let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
1.Inside package.json, remove ^ from "firebase": "^4.8.1"

1.1 Downgrade Firebase from 4.8.1 to 4.8.0 by changing 4.8.1 to 4.8.0

1.2 End result should look like this: "firebase": "4.8.0"

2. Run npm update in the Project Root. NPM will downgrade Firebase for ya

3. Run ng serve --open to check for compilation errors. There shouldn't be any.
```

Reason:

Firebase had introduced some breaking changes that AngularFire2 had not coped up with yet. Until the AngularFire2 team work it out, this will be the solution.

Add a thumbs up emoji and direct anyone having the same trouble here! Would save a lot of their time!

Comment: You forgot to add a link [to the original comment](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387#issuecomment-353778579). And we don't really have emojis here :)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387#issuecomment-353778579

Comment: You can edit your answer (look for "edit" button under the text)