# Visual Studio Code integrated terminal: error TS5023: Unknown option 'w' when executing tsc -w command from integrated terminal

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am getting error for `tsc -w` command in VS Code integrated terminal. But I am able to run it from NodeJs Command promopt.

```
`error TS5023: Unknown option 'w'
Use the '--help' flag to see options.
Version 1.0.3.0
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ..]
Examples: tsc hello.ts
      tsc --out foo.js foo.ts
      tsc @args.txt`
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301451/how-to-upgrade-typescript-to-the-latest-version. The latest version of Typescript is 2.6.1. The version that application is using is quite old.

Comment: @Richards: Thank you Richards. I had installed typescript latest version.By following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301451/how-to-upgrade-typescript-to-the-latest-version) , I got to know, I have 2 versions C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript , 1.0 & 2.1. So `tsc --version` was showing 1.0.3.0. I deleted 1.0 folder. Now the version is showing correctly as 2.6.1 and `tsc -w` command is working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

just delete old versions from path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0 or desired v, then just tsc --version from terminal